# Numbers $N\equiv abab$ s.t. $N-1$ is a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

I want to find all the numbers of the form $N\equiv abab$ (with $a\neq 0$) such that $N-1$ is a perfect square.

I am stuck. I know that such N can be written as $N=101(10a+b)$, but I don't know how to proceed.

Any idea or usual trick in this kind of problems is welcome.

Comment: Are $a,b$ meant to be digits?  If so, then there really aren't very many cases to test.

Comment: Yes, they are digits. It's about 90 cases to check (if im not wrong). But this is not proper mathematical way to answer. I al looking for a strong mathematical argument that allow me to solve the question.

Comment: It's considerably fewer than $90$, since there are only a few values $b$ can take.

Comment: Thanks for the comment lulu. How can you discard values for $b$?

Comment: All squares end in one of $0,1,4,5,6,9$.

Comment: Ok, thats true, but still gives 54 possibilities. Maybe, is this the best result we can achieve by using mathematical reasoning?

Comment: Well, you could also remark that all squares are either $0$ or $1\pmod 4$, so $10a+b\equiv 1$ or $2\pmod 4$.  That also eliminates a lot of cases.  To be honest, though,  I just searched all $90$ cases..it was easier to do that than to eliminate cases.

Comment: Thanks lulu for your comments, they were helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $a$ and $b$ are standing in for single digits, not strings of digits.

Note that if $n\ge 100$, then $n^2 = N - 1$ has at least $5$ digits and therefore cannot be in the form $abab - 1$. This means that we need only consider perfect squares of numbers $n \lt 100$.

We can easily write a Python script to do this for us:

```
for n in range(1, 100):
    N = n**2 + 1
    if N % 100 == (N - N % 100) / 100:
        print(n)
```

This code prints out the values $10$ and $91$, which correspond to $(a,b) = (0,1)$ and $(8,2)$.

Comment: @lulu Forgive my sloppiness. It appears the OP is looking for a different approach to the problem anyhow. :P

Comment: Oh, no worries.  I'm with you...there are so few candidates, the temptation to just run a quick search is pretty strong.  If there were no solutions, I'd expect there to be a simple argument to see that, but as there are solutions I'm skeptical that trying to find a clever way in will save any time at all.

Comment: Thanks Franklin for your answer. It's good to know that 8282 os the only non trivial solution. However i am afraid i'm not allowed to use computers on my exams.

Comment: @Senna Since $N$ is a multiple of the prime $101$, we need a solution of the congruence $x^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{101}$. Unless one is distracted, the fact that $101 = 10^2 + 1$ jumps out. Thus the candidates for $\sqrt{N-1}$ are $10$ and $101-10 = 91$ (since larger integers $\equiv \pm 10 \pmod{101}$ don't have squares with at most four digits).

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you. That was really an elegant solution.